# Accessing few frames only in an OME-TIFF format

Tags: python, image, tiff

I am using the [tifffile](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/code/tifffile.py.html) package for processing OME-TIFF files. My OME-TIFF file contains > 6000 images and I would like to read only a number of frames from the whole file.

Is it possible to access the nth up to (n+m)th frame without reading the whole file?

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1):

I found that this works

> images = TiffFile(file).asarray(key=np.arange(n,n+m))